# Is this a valid inference in propositional logic?

Tags: propositional-calculus

As part of a proof I have $\vdash p \to (q \to r)$. Can I from this infer $\vdash (p \wedge q) \to r$? It "feels" correct, but I can't seem to find a proof.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$

$$\fitch{p\to (q\to r)}{\fitch{p\wedge q}{q\\p\\q\to r\\r}\\(p\wedge q)\to r}\qquad\fitch{(p\wedge q)\to r}{\fitch{p}{\fitch{q}{p\wedge q\\ r}\\q\to r}\\p\to (q\to r)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can.

- Propositions-as-types proof: if you have a function $f: P \to (Q \to R)$, you can define a function $f' : P \times Q \to R$ by $f'(p, q) := f(p)(q)$.
- Valuations proof: just do the truth table. $p \to (q \to r)$ is false iff $p$ is true but $q \to r$ is false: that is, iff $p$ is true, $q$ is true, $r$ is false. On the other hand, $p \wedge q \to r$ is false iff $p \wedge q$ is true but $r$ is false; and that's obviously the same.
- Deduction theorem: the first one is $p, q \vdash r$; the second one is $p \wedge q \vdash r$. Those are manifestly the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the third kind, one using deduction theorem

Answer (score 1):

By applying appropriate theorems to convert the LHS to RHS:

**In this case:**
$p→(q→r)$ is the *LHS*
$p→(q→r)$ is the *RHS*

**Formulas Required:**
$a→b ≡ ¬a∨b$
$¬(a∧b) ≡ ¬a∨¬b$

**Steps:**
$p→(q→r) ≡ p→(¬q∨r) ≡ ¬p∨(¬q∨r) ≡ (¬p∨¬q)∨r ≡ ¬(p∧q)∨r ≡ (p∧q)→r$